# In A Clockwork Orange did Alex actually want to be reformed

Tags: a-clockwork-orange

In *A Clockwork Orange* (1971), Alex DeLarge tries to convince the catholic priest in the story that he is a changed young citizen and wants desperately to be reformed no matter what the cost.

The question here: Did Alex actually seek to truly be reformed properly or was he just expecting it not to work so he could get released and go commit more crimes?

Answer (score 6):

It's not possible to be sure but I don't believe he had any serious desire to be "reformed" -- I think he was just looking for a way out of prison and wasn't expecting anything like what actually happened to him.

First, it is clear throughout from the narration, his actions, his expressions, that the ultra-violence is not motivated by anything except desire (any stolen money, etc., was just secondary), he truly gets off on it, and has no sense of guilt over it.  If that is not convincing enough, look at his revelry at the end of the movie when they reverse the "treatment".

I don't think he ever had a "change of heart".